# Android SpeechRecognizer with USB Microphone

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have written this sample app to convert speech to text with [SpeechRecognizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer) API from Android.

This works as expected when there's an inbuilt microphone on the device.

But it doesn't seem to detect the audio from a USB Microphone.

USB Device: Jabra Speak 510 UC (PHS002W)

Note: A normal Audio Recorder app picks up the audio input and records fine on the same Android device.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final Integer RecordAudioRequestCode = 1;
private SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer;
private TextView speechHistory;
private Button recordVoiceBtn, clearBtn;
private List<String> voiceInputHistory = new ArrayList<>();
private boolean isListening = false;
private Activity thisActivity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    thisActivity = this;

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    boolean micPresent = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_MICROPHONE);

    speechHistory = findViewById(R.id.speechHistory);
    recordVoiceBtn = findViewById(R.id.recordVoiceBtn);
    clearBtn = findViewById(R.id.clearBtn);
    speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);

    final Intent speechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());

    speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float v) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] bytes) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
            ArrayList<String> data = bundle.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
            voiceInputHistory.add(data.get(0));
            StringBuilder fullHistory = new StringBuilder();
            for (String inputText : voiceInputHistory) {
                fullHistory.append(inputText).append("\n");
            }
            speechHistory.setText(fullHistory.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }
    });

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        checkPermission();
    }

    recordVoiceBtn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
    recordVoiceBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (!isListening) {
            isListening = true;
            speechRecognizer.startListening(speechRecognizerIntent);
            recordVoiceBtn.setText("Stop Listening");
            recordVoiceBtn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        } else {
            isListening = false;
            recordVoiceBtn.setText("Start Listening");
            speechRecognizer.stopListening();
            recordVoiceBtn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
        }
    });
    clearBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        isListening = false;
        recordVoiceBtn.setText("Start Listening");
        speechRecognizer.stopListening();
        recordVoiceBtn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
        voiceInputHistory.clear();
        speechHistory.setText("Your Speech History");
    });

    if (!micPresent) {
        clearBtn.setEnabled(false);
        recordVoiceBtn.setEnabled(false);
        speechHistory.setText("No Mic Detected");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    speechRecognizer.destroy();
}

private void checkPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, RecordAudioRequestCode);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == RecordAudioRequestCode && grantResults.length > 0) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

Why is this? How to capture the audio from a USB Mic for SpeechRecognizer API?

Comment: any idea how to feed speech recognition engine with "data"? e.g. from file, streamed, generated... (yes, I know its offtop, but as you are in topic maybe you know any way...)

Comment: @snachmsm I don't think this API supports this requirement. Maybe check the Speech API.

Comment: well, good point, but I also need standalone solution, offline, forgot to say... nvm, thanks for suggestion, glad you've found (own) answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Realized it didn't have anything to do with the USB Device.

```
SpeechRecognizer: no selected voice recognition service
```

The targeted device didn't have Google services. Installing them fixed the issue.